# Slowing down users from downloading/saving html5 video

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, security, video

I already know that once user started to watch html5 video he already has it, but unfortunately not so many users are smart and can even save the video with right click, if you know what I mean. So what I want to do is to slow down users from saving videos from my site. The idea is generate new link on every new request. For example once I load into video the link of this video should change and when the user does save link request he gets not found. So actually what I need is store link on every url refresh to the session and check it this link wasn't used already. Is the idea is right or wrong? Maybe you can offer other ways to do this? Thanks for answers.

P.S. I am using ruby on rails framework v4.2.4

Comment: Maybe you will use some kind of Javascript Player that will stream video from your web app.

Comment: Have you tried this https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/3174601 ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably save some time if you use something like [CloudFront secure streaming](http://www.secretmike.com/2011/10/aws-cloudfront-secure-streaming.html).

If you want to roll your own:

1. create link to the video at runtime, which includes the user's ip address, and a short expiration time. Sign these values with an HMAC. Put the HMAC in the URL.
2. on your video streaming server, check the user's ip address and expiration time against the HMAC and if correct, make sure user's ip matches the one in the link and that current_time <= expiration time.

Your web server and video streaming server will need a shared secret.

This prevents user's from sharing links (outside of their local network anyways).